How does "instant knowledge" happen?
2 distinct events happened that got me interested in the Process of Understanding.
First, once so happened that I knew something for many years but one day "it clicked"?! I became very interested in what happened in that Instant?! How could it make sense in an INSTANT!!!
Second one happened!!! when one day while reading about Triangles a Question popped up in my Mind, Why is Sum of Internal Angles of a Triangle is 180 Degrees, why not 200 or 250 something. I Googled, you can google now, there is no answer, so now I didn't have any other source, so I Drew a big triangle on Geogebra and watched it for 1.5 days, on second day as I was getting up for lunch and as my eyes were about to leave the screen, in an instant, all of the below that I am about to write below, all that information, knowledge happened IN AN INSTANT?!!!! HOW????!!!!! Definitely there is some other mechanism, other than words.
"A line is 180 Degrees, Straight Angle. If you disturb that line, meaning bend it, it'll need minimum 3 foldes to come back to exact same direction, hence 3 arms and since 180 degrees was disturbed, that's why 180 Degrees is compensated, also if you add another arm and make it square, you won't be adding 90 Degrees to the Sum of Internal Angles but 180 Degrees because you added one extra line and Bent it TOO, so now these four lines are compensation 2 bent lines hence 360 Degrees"
Can all of this knowledge be transferred via words so fast? There has to be some other agent for such a knowledge transfer?
I read other question related to "knowing" or "understanding" but none specific to mechanism. Are there studies related to this?! Is THIS a field of Study?
Thanks Much in Advance.

Since there's no time in any math numbers, equations or functions, it seems at that click instant your mind levitated to the Platonic heaven?...

This is known as the Eureka effect, "common human experience of suddenly understanding a previously incomprehensible problem or concept", and it has been extensively studied by psychologists:"Some research suggest that insight problems are difficult to solve because of our mental fixation on the inappropriate aspects of the problem content... Insight is believed to occur with a break in mental fixation, allowing the solution to appear transparent and obvious."

Background processing. I learned long ago that sometimes the best thing I could do with a problem was make sure I understood the requirements, then set it aside before trying to find the solution  the brain continues some kinds of data processing even without conscious attention.

Hey @keshlam Thanks, this question is PRECISELY ABOUT "some kinds of data processing". I wanted to know the Mechanism in the Mind that makes all of this happen.

If you are trying to understand the mechanisms of the brain, you might want to investigate psychology, biology, and psychiatry rather than philosophy. I don't think these mechanisms are visible to the mind except by observing that they happen.

@DoubleKnot It seems that way, what I wanted to know is, HOW it got levitated? After reading some suggested links it seems there is no simple answer to this... Lator Gator. Thanks for all the help...

Hey @DoubleKnot I was thinking about all the comments that I got on my past two questions; yours were the only ones I could not make a head or tail of. Went completely beyond my radar, what do you think I am Missing, WHAT is IT that I Don't Know. Well truth be told, other than my GuruJi I don't know much but still...

If there were a IT in the imagery scene of your mind, then IT must be extremely stable, free energy as a physics jargon, or eidetic as Husseurl’s phenomenology jargon from his Logical Investigation series, otherwise even seeing the transcendental Eureka-type sharp and distinct images while dwelling in a quiet math class without what I coined philomorphism, you'll still get confused, say, when staring at a truth table or a Russel set or a Godel sentence from nowhere…

@DoubleKnot I have realised that I am very GOOD with "Static ITs", like Definitions, Axioms, Primitives, but when IT Moves, as in Logic where you I have to jump hoops with all those Definitions, Axioms etc. weighing in on my Head, eideticness is Lost. Believe me being a Self Learner I know bits and pieces here and there of Logic and Math but all that Knowledge hasn't coaleased into a coherent whole. So if the answer to my question lies in some other complicated area of the subject then I am lost. I usually am looking for simple answers but I guess there aren't OFTEN...

This is the description of epiphany: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(feeling)

An epiphany is an experience of a sudden and striking realization. Generally the term is used to describe a scientific breakthrough or a religious or philosophical discovery, but it can apply in any situation in which an enlightening realization allows a problem or situation to be understood from a new and deeper perspective. Epiphanies are studied by psychologists and other scholars, particularly those attempting to study the process of innovation.

also see Is there a philosophical term or theory that defines or describes the idea of 'epiphany'?
Since this is more of a psychological question, not much else to say here.

I VTC, but epiphanic insights are probably defensibly a form of intuition, which has an SEP article.

I won't say intuitions are completely unrelated, but I think the question describes epiphany, not intuition.
